# Plotly express is not rendered in jupyter lab

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-express

The following code does not render in Jupyter lab:

```
%matplotlib widget
import plotly.express as px  
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
px.bar(df, x='A', y='B')
```

[image]
I have tried to install all the dependencies and extensions mentioned in here
https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35

but also the steps in here 
https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib

Nothing worked

Here is my set up:

```
jupyter lab --version
1.0.2

python --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

conda list jupyterlab
# packages in environment at C:\Users\***\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyterlab                1.0.2            py36hf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                   py36_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_0

conda list nodejs
# packages in environment at C:\Users\***\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
nodejs                    0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi

conda list plotly
# packages in environment at C:\Users\***\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
plotly                    4.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
plotly-express            0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

EDIT:

```
jupyter-labextension list
JupyterLab v1.0.2
Known labextensions:
   app dir: C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v1.0.2 enabled  ok
        @jupyterlab/git v0.8.0 enabled  ok
        @jupyterlab/plotly-extension v1.0.0 enabled  ok
        jupyter-matplotlib v0.4.2 enabled  ok
        jupyterlab-chart-editor v1.2.0 enabled  ok
        jupyterlab-plotly v1.1.0 enabled  ok
        plotlywidget v1.1.0 enabled  ok
```

Comment: DId you install the jupyterlab plotly extension, it works for me with a fresh install

Comment: yes, I did. Any command I can use to show you the extensions are installed?

Comment: jupyter-labextension list

Comment: thanks, edited my question with that information as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: these instructions and more are now in our official [Troubleshooting Guide](https://plot.ly/python/troubleshooting/)!

It could be that remnants of previous installations or attempts at installation are causing issues. I recommend either starting with a clean install or uninstalling all Plotly modules (from both pip and conda!) and plotly-related jlab extensions, and then following the instructions here: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

Uninstalling the module is a matter of

```
conda uninstall plotly
pip uninstall plotly
```

And then reinstalling with one or the other but not both, according to the instructions linked above.

Uninstalling JupyterLab extensions is performed with

```
jupyter labextension uninstall @jupyterlab/plotly-extension
jupyter labextension uninstall jupyterlab-plotly 
jupyter labextension uninstall plotlywidget
```

Comment: that's possible - could you mention the sequence of commands I should write using pip and conda to uninstall all plotly related modules and extensions?

Comment: It’s much easier to start from a fresh conda env or virtualenv to be honest :)

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to include some uninstallation notes

Answer (score 3):

Following the official plotly.py repo https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py, for correct rendering of plotly in JupyterLab there's a need to installing the special extension by command

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem but with a different cause and requiring a different solution. Just thought I'd share it for anyone encountering the same issue.

I'm running jupyterlab in a Docker container which did not yet have nodejs or npm installed.

I was unable to install the required extension via:

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly
```

Because it gave me this error:

```
ValueError: Please install nodejs and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.
```

Conda was not available on the container and when installing node and npm via the jupyterlab terminal (through pip or apt-get) I got the same error, or a version mismatch (when using apt-get the nodejs version I got was too old).

The following steps helped me solve the problem.

- Install nvm in the docker container when building the container, thus in the Dockerfile:

  - `RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`
  - Mind the version number, you might want to change that to whatever is the latest stable version
- Make the nvm command available by loading some included init scripts:

  - `SHELL ["bash", "-lc"]` <-- Only necessary if your container is not using bash as shell already
  - `RUN export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`
  - `RUN [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`
  - `RUN [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`
- Install a specific nodejs version via nvm:

  - `RUN nvm install 14.17.0`
  - Mind the version number again, change to whatever version you need.
- Install the jupyter extension:

  - `RUN jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly`

Restart the kernel and happy plotting ;)

You might also consider installing conda and then nodejs via conda if that makes sense for your use case. I have not tested if that works though.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing jupyterlab dash, it worked for me!

you can do it through the jupyterlab menu or by following these instructions.

https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash

It looks like you should upgrade your plotly as well, because plotly express is now part of plotly i.e.

```
import plotly.express as px
```

Comment: I have tried importing it in both ways: plotly_express and plotly.express. both failed. see last edit

Comment: I do have dash now: `jupyterlab-dash v0.1.0-alpha.3 enabled  ok`
Closed and reopened jupyterlab. Problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling to make this work – these steps worked for me:

- If you have jupyter lab running – shut down your session.
- Uninstall plotly and all other related packages like @nicolaskruchten [recommends here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57452256/7117003).
- Make a fresh install of plotly and [jupyter-dash](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash) with EITHER conda or pip, but do **not** mix between both package managers.
- Execute `jupyter lab` from terminal again. Now you should see a window `Build recommended – jupyterlab-dash needs to be included in build`. Confirm this.
- After the successful build close the jupyter-lab session and initiate again.