# How to show Plotly figures in JupyterLab 3+?

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab

I am running JupyterLab 3.0.6 and Plotly 4.14.1. It seems all the plotly dash plugins are outdated? Is there any extension that works with JupyterLab 3 yet?

E.g.

```
import plotly.express as px
px.line([1,2,3,2])
```

Only shows an empty output.

Comment: FYI: In June 2022, with Python 3.9, jupyterlab 3.3.2, plotly 5.8.2, ipywidgets 7.7.0, I also got no errors and empty output.  I thought restarting the kernel was enough for the pip installs and imports to take effect.  But they didn't.  Instead, I had to kill and restart jupyterlab itself for the Plotly graph to become visible.

Comment: Looping through different renderers worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064245/plot-ly-offline-mode-in-jupyter-lab-not-displaying-plots

Answer (score 2):

It is working now.

```
conda install -c plotly plotly=4.14.3
conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.5"
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3
# OPTIONAL: Jupyter widgets extension
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager plotlywidget@4.14.3
```

https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/

Comment: If this is actually necessary for JupyterLab 3, that linked guide should be updated. [The JupyterLab section](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#JupyterLab-Support) currently says _"jupyterlab>=3 and ipywidgets>=7.6 contain everything you need to run JupyterLab."_ Then it gives `labextension` commands _"for JupyterLab 2 or earlier."_

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered by one of the plotly developers.

[Plotly express is not rendered in jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450868/plotly-express-is-not-rendered-in-jupyter-lab)

Edit: That link is old sorry. After some more research it appears jupyter lab 3 is not currently compatible with plotly. They are currently working on it.

https://community.plotly.com/t/jupyterlab-plotly-not-compatible-with-jupyterlab-3-0/48777

Comment: Of course, plotly plots are rendered in JupyterLab. E.g. Jupyter Lab 2.2.6 or so. My question is addressing the latest version of JupyterLab (3+)

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt realize that post was jupyter lab 2. I updated my answer.

Comment: JupyterLab 3 has always been supported, and is even better-supported as of `plotly` v5, with a federated extension :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment
[How to show Plotly figures in JupyterLab 3+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502866/how-to-show-plotly-figures-in-jupyterlab-3#comment121678652_68837172)
with JupyterLab 3.x and Plotly 5.x labextension installation of plotly is outdated.

Installation:
https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#installation

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer that worked for me on JupyterLab 4.0.5

- Install plotly `pip install plotly`
- Install ipywidgets `pip install ipywidgets`
- Specify the renderer as mentioned [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/unable-to-display-plotly-figures-output/13628/5) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800700/8576801)

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

# At least one of these should work
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe' # or 'notebook' or 'colab' or 'jupyterlab'

fig = px.scatter(df, x, y)
```

Then I could actually see the plot!

Answer (score 0):

As described by @piedpiper in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77320500/23203605, **pio.renderers.default** is the key in my JupyterLab 3 setup.

This fixed my problem:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe'
```

Answer (score -1):

To install Plotly on JupyterLab 3 on ubuntu is necessary to install nodejs, npm and jupyterlab plotly extension

The [instructions on the plotly](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support) website didn't worked for me. The graph was being rendered as a white square. I discovered that jupyterlab plotly extension is working, but on Ubuntu it depends on nodejs and npm.

```sh
apt install nodejs npm
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly
```

Reestart the jupyter and it should be working like the example bellow.

[image]

Comment: This is out of date as of version 5.x of `plotly`